# How to use custom content to show the grid's tooltip?

Tags: tooltip, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to use custom content to show the grid's tooltip? I want to show the tooltio ofcoloumn 2 and coloumn 3 ,and the content is  a span which id called spanid or div which is called divid?

```
var tooltip = $("#Grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: "td",
        width: 120,
        position: "top",
        content: value
    }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

I try to write this,but it seems wrong.

```
var tooltip = $("#Grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: "td[3n]||td[2n]",
        width: 120,
        position: "top",
        content: divid.html
    }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working code for my scenario, it will work tool tip for all product names with class **pLink**

```
$(".pLink")
    .kendoTooltip(
    {
        content: kendo.template($("#toolTipTemplate").html()),
        position: "top",
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        animation: {
            close: { effects: "fadeOut zoom:out", duration: 300 },
            open: { effects: "fadeIn zoom:in", duration: 300 }
        }
    });

<script id="toolTipTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                <p class="tooltipProductName">#=target.data('title')#</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //show the tooltip
            tooltip = $("#grdData").kendoTooltip({
                filter: 'td:not(:first-child, :nth-child(2), :empty)',
})
```

this will allow you to select first column , second column and it will also filter out empty cells. You can use the nth child selector. As this is a CSS3 selector, it will work from IE9+, chrome and firefox won't be an issue.

Hope this helps !